# about SQl query two

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

this is my code in c# :

```
objConnection = new SqlConnection("server = localhost;initial catalog = instrument;integrated security = true");
objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
objDataSet = new MyDataSet();
objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from kala where [I_Group] like '%'+ @I_Group and [I Price] between @min and @max", objConnection);
objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@I_Group", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbSearch.SelectedIndex + 1;
objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@min", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblMinGrade.Text;
objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@max", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblMaxGrade.Text;
objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "kala");
dataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSet;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "ITable";
```

I create a table in sql server , that name is (ITable) and this table include 2 fields (I Group , I Price)...i want to show my data where I Price is between min and max
but this code not work!!!
and an important question that this sql code not support by stored procedure
and I Group type is int and I price is varchar(50)
please help me!!!

Comment: "this code not work" doesn't give any indication of what's wrong - and your last sentence doesn't really make sense. Please clarify your question.

Comment: is your first condition is working ie [I_Group] like '%'+ @I_Group

Comment: Please be more clarify my persian dude, are you sure your query is correct?

Comment: Are you using SQL or MySQL? You've tagged this with both and they are different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your remaining query is working fine.
Please check below query. This query is not tested.
Please let me know if this query is working fine ?

Your [I Price] column's datatype is VARCHAR(50). Please change that to int.
I think that will be the main issue for your query.

SQl Cannot Compare the data which is in String (varchar) format.

If you wants to compare the data in SQL then your data should be in following format :

```
Integers,
Dates etc...
```

Here's Query

```
SELECT
* 
FROM
kala 
where 
[I_Group] like '%'+ @I_Group 
AND [I Price] <= @min 
AND [I Price] >= @max
```